# Alternativas para método obsoleto document.execCommand

Tags: javascript, html5, angular

Estou tentando fazer um editor de texto para que os usuarios do meu site possam criar paginas html ("postagens") atráves dele,a muito tempo atrás eu desenvolvi uma [solução](https://editor-de-texto-beryl.vercel.app/) para isso utilizando div com contenteditable e o método document.execCommand, porém ele esta atualmente obsoleto.

Alguém conhece alguma alternativa de solução para o meu problema ?

Pensei em criar algo parecido com o próprio editor do stackoverflow que suporta o markdown, e posteriormente minha pagina de postagens iria traduzir esse MD. Essa seria um boa solução ?